Is my Mac Mini frying its USB-C memory sticks with hot fan air?
I buy top shelf USB sticks - Samsung, Sandisk, etc.  so we can cross off "cheap USB".
I've had an ongoing problem with short service life out of USB-C sticks in my Mac Mini, which I use to hold 100GB-tier games (too big for internal storage).  The USB sticks seem to be taking thermal damage.
I notice the USB-C ports on the Mac Mini are directly above the fan outlet. The air output is pretty hot when I'm gaming, but generally, the system seems to run the fan as slow as possible that will prevent overheating. So the air output is always quite hot.
But on the other hand, it is airflow, so maybe that's better than no airflow.
My USB-3 sticks, not over the fan outlet, don't have this problem, but they are also not as high performance.
So my question is - is it a mistake to put USB sticks in the USB-C ports on the Mac Mini, given the fan position?  And if so, what should I be doing instead? Will USB-C extension cords be reliable?

You can try using some high speed docks or extension cables.
